# Highcharts plotlines above area using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I want plotlines to be rendered the last(right now area is overlaying them). If i use Zindex width increases and it doesn't look as neath, i also try line-width. 
I did this approach for markers to be above plotlines but it doesnt work for plotlines above area. Am i doing something wrong?

```
componentDidRender() {
if(this.shadowRoot) {
var markers0 = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.highcharts-markers.highcharts-series-0');
  var plotLines0 = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.highcharts-plot-lines-4');
  var area0 = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.highcharts-area-series');

/// plotlines below markers - works
  if(plotLines0 && plotLines0.parentNode && markers0)
     plotLines0.parentNode.insertBefore(markers0, plotLines0.nextSibling);

// markers below area - works 
 // markers0.parentNode.insertBefore(area0, markers0.nextSibling);

//area below plotlines- doesnt work
  //if(area0 && area0.parentNode && plotLines0)
  //area0.parentNode.insertBefore(plotLines0, area0.nextSibling);
```

if i run that code for area below plotlines nothing changes.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a jsfiddle reproducing your chart.

Comment: i have a fiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/warnisw/mk9cswjr/680/  just to clarify my question is it possible to show plotlines without using Zindex? Like insert before or appendchild

Comment: Hi Arnis, Why do not you want to use `zIndex` property? The `plotLines` can be rendered above or under the points: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/btfhwv1s/

Comment: because it makes lines look thicker. I want plain grid lines but its not possible because i have to redraw one of the plot lines( i dont see a way to remove 1 specific grid line either)  . The method i use can set which element will be rendered the last but for some reason it doesn't work for the area.

Comment: @Arnis, I think that the line does not look as if it were thicker. You can remove one specific grid line in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rxku74cd/

Comment: @ppotaczek that is the correct way. I will leave the grid lines and remove one of them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the second to last grid line by:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var prevTick;

            Highcharts.objectEach(this.yAxis[0].ticks, function(tick) {
                if (tick.isLast) {
                    prevTick.gridLine.destroy();
                }

                prevTick = tick;
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/obam5yxg/